# In Rails 2 yielding a block in a helper a method renders partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

Rails 2.2.2

_competition.html.erb

```
<p>This is packed</p>
<% pack do %>
// some javascript
<% end %>
```

competitions_helper.rb

```
def pack(&block)
  yield + 'PACKED'
end
```

However 'PACKED' does not get appended to my javascript string, its as if `pack do` has no effect. It seems like there is some oddness going off with context of the blocks and the actual view rendering because if I remove the call to yield in the helper and return a hard coded string I get no output from pack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def pack(&block)
  concat(capture(&block) + 'PACKED')
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't test it, but you could try:

```
yield << 'PACKED'
```

It is just a different way of combining 2 strings.

Comment: Thanks but, the issue isn't with the way the strings are concat'd. If I do not yield, and just return a string it works as expected. Calling yield seems to re-render the partial (which calls the helper).

Answer (score 0):

As a work around, for the time being, putting the javascript in another partial and passing it to the helper function using `render_to_string`, ie. without the need to call `yield` works.

```
<%= pack(render_to_string :partial => '_competition_javascript') %>
```